# How can I intelligently sync directories on Linux?

Tags: linux, backup, sync, merge

I have two directories on my Linux system that I want to sync. Most of the contents of these directories are the same, however some files differ:

Directory A contains:

```
File 1
File 2
File 4
File 5
```

Directory B contains:

```
File 1
File 2
File 3
File 5
```

After synchronization, I want both directory A and directory B to contain:

```
File 1
File 2
File 3
File 4
File 5
```

This is an example, the real directories contain thousands of files and their size is several GBs.

How can I do this on Linux?

**Update**: What if File 1, 2, 4, 5 are not in directory A but in a subdirectory AA that is in directory A? The files in directory B remain the same. After syncing, I don't want to end up with multiple copies of File 1, 2, 5.

Comment: `rsync`, making sure you don't use `--delete`?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is `rsync`:

```
$ cd -- "$(mktemp --directory)
$ mkdir A B
$ touch A/File\ {1,2,4,5}
$ touch B/File\ {1,2,3,5}
$ rsync -a A/ B
$ rsync -a B/ A
$ ls A B
A:
'File 1'  'File 2'  'File 3'  'File 4'  'File 5'

B:
'File 1'  'File 2'  'File 3'  'File 4'  'File 5'
```

`rsync` will transport only the files necessary to sync up the directories. Unlike other *nix tools the slash after the first directory name is significant - it indicates that the *content* of the source directory rather than the directory itself should be copied.

Comment: What if File 1, 2, 4, 5 are not in directory A but in a subdirectory AA that is in directory A? The files in directory B remain the same. After syncing, I don't want to end up with multiple copies of File 1, 2, 5. Is rsync smart enough to avoid this? An option that hashes the files synced to prevent duplicates should work.

Comment: Do you mean if you have A/AA/1 and B/1, both with the same content, you *don't* want to copy 1? If so, that's a completely different problem from the original.

Comment: Yes. I only want to make sure File 1 is both in A and B somewhere (can be A/1 or A/subdir/1, I don't care). As long as it is in both A and B it's fine. If I have A/AA/1 and B/1 as you said, I guess rsync would also create A/1 and B/AA/1 which is unnecessary because I would have File 1 in A both as A/1 and A/AA/1 and in B as B/1 and B/AA/1, which is redundant. I will create a new question if this is complicated and completely different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both directories `A` and `B` are in the same level

```
$ rsync -a A/ B/ & rsync -a B/ A/
```